# Spell-checking homophones and numbers with spacy

Tags: spell-checking, spacy

I am working with a pipeline where speech is translated into text. The speech would be a sort of technical professional jargon, with occurences of acronyms as well as phrases which describe amounts and values.
There is a high chance that the stock speech-to-text translator is gonna misrepresent terms and phrases I would be interested in. I have a corpus where I can tag those words and phrases.
Is there a way to use spacy (or maybe some other NLP tool) to apply spell-checking, so for instance 'pee-age' or 'pee-oh-to' would be corrected to 'pH' and 'pO2', respectively?
Also, for phrases where numbers and amounts are specified, like for example 'one twenty cee-cee' would be corrected to '120cc'?
Thanks in advance